# Git Bash how to show info about repo files like in Git Shell

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I`m working with Git Bash on Windows. But before, I was working with Git Shell (from github). In Git Shell was this really awesome thing, See the image below:

[image]

In Git Shell, **I do not need to use `git status` to see how many untracked, changed or deleted file I had.** Git Shell shows that information after any command.

How can I do this for Git Bash (on Windows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply manipulate the `PS1` variable, something like this might help you:

```
$ PS1="$PS1 [`git diff --shortstat`]> "
```

The result should be something like this:

```
rlegendi@localhost /.../gitrepo (master)
[ 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+)] >
```

So basically you have to add this like to your `profile` file (either at the Git installation directory typically under `c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc` or in your home directory). That way you can create a bit nicer version.

Take a look on `PROMPT_COMMAND` and different [git diff switches](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) (like `--numstat`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, I found solution for me:

Comment: in ...\Git\etc\profile i add: `PROMPT_COMMAND="git diff --shortstat"`, now result looks like this: http://files.artemzin.ru/img/stackoverflow/git_prompt_diff.png